# Merge accounts to use OpenID

Tags: support, jobs, user-accounts

Would it be possible to merge my accounts on Careers?
This is my main account I would like to keep, http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/221432, but I would like to associate the OpenID used with this account as well, http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/296779

Comment: Use email to `team@stackexchange.com` instead of a public post here, they can help you better.

Comment: @Richard actually careers got its own email: careers@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

emailed you at one of your email addresses... In general per @sha-wiz-dow-ard, these requests are best sent to careers@stackoverflow.com