# Moving job listing to another Careers account

Tags: support, jobs, merge-accounts

Our HR person create a job listing in Careers under her account. I then realized that we can't have more than one user associated with our company, so we probably want to link our OpenIDs to the same account so we can both access it.

I am a long-standing user of StackOverflow with a bunch of questions/answers, so ideally I'd like to add her OpenID to my account. For this to work, however, we need to move the paid job listing to my Careers account, delete her account and add her OpenID to my account. I don't care about sharing the StackOverflow login since she isn't a programmer and won't be asking/answering questions anyway.

Is this possible? I can't see any way to move the job listing to another account. I tried to add her OpenID to my Careers account hoping that would merge them, but it just told me that an account with that ID already exists.

Comment: This is best done by email see the answer to [this other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182799/152859).

Comment: Okay will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careers accounts are separate from SO accounts, but we can merge both of your careers accounts. Will email you to finalize. In general, per @sha-wiz-dow-ard merge request should be emailed to careers@stackoverflow.com